# System.Data.SQLite issue with "IN" clause in query

Tags: c#, sqlite, compact-framework, windows-ce, system.data.sqlite

I am working on compact framework and using ADO for sqlite. My sqlite database consist of 3 million records. The table structure is same as explain in
[THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119713/system-data-sqlite-issue-on-compact-framework-3-5). I am trying to use a Data Adapter and Data Set to solve the issue mentioned in same question. However the new issue am facing is, whenever my query contains "IN" clause the data adapter's Fill(...) call does not return. Below is the query and logic I am using for filling data set.

```
string query = SELECT TimeStamp,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6 FROM T1 
           WHERE (TimeStamp BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate)
           AND Col5 IN {0} ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT 0,@dataToRead
```

**Please note 'place holder' after IN clause**. I required because my IN clause list will be created
dynamically.

I am using the sqlite command and data adapter as follows

```
using (SQLiteCommand cmd = _conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", startDate.Ticks);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", endDate.Ticks);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataToRead", dataToRead); //100
StringBuilder inParams = new StringBuilder();
if (true == webRequest && webRequestFilter != WebCategory.All)
{
  switch (webRequestFilter)
  {
             case WebCategory.One:
             {
                inParams.AppendFormat("({0})", (int)SystemCategory.One); 
                break;
             }
             case WebCategory.Two:
             {
              inParams.AppendFormat("({0},{1},{2})", (int)SystemCategory.Two,
                                              (int)SystemCategory.Three,
                                              (int)SystemCategory.Four);
              break;
             }
            case WebCategory.Three:
            {
                 inParams.AppendFormat("({0})", (int)SystemCategory.Five);
                 break;
            }
          case WebCategory.Four:
           {
                 inParams.AppendFormat("({0},{1},{2})", (int)SystemCategory.Six,
                                        (int)SystemCategory.Two,
                                        (int)SystemCategory.Three);
                 break;
           }
       }// End Switch
      query = string.Format(query, inParams.ToString()); //Append place holder for IN clause
    }// End If
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);    // This call does not return.
}
```

The query works well with Sqlite Shell and
same database.

Has anyone faced the similar issue with compact framework?

Comment: can you post your full code in the using() also what is query please format this so that it leads to no assumptions also where is _conn defined.. it's hard to offer advice when you are piecing out code like this also what do you mean infinite loop are you getting and stackoverflow errors at all..?

Comment: Hi Dj Kraze, Please see the post again. I have removed statement "infinite loop" because it was misleading. Also, the _conn variable is initialized when application is started and kept alive till application ends.

Comment: after your da.Fill(ds) clause, are you binding it to anything like a dataGridView for example..? also please show more code for example if you have the @startDate and @endDate.. how are you adding those Parameters.. do you have something like this `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(SqlParameter("@startDate", yourStartDateValue));`

Comment: Hi Dj Kraze, No I am not binding to datagrid or data view. I want to enumerate the data set row by row and want to create the Object list as mentioned in my previous question. Please see updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build your inParams *before* assigning your query variable as the CommandText and *before* adding any other parameters.  I think that it is resetting your Parameters collection when you assign to the .CommandText property. Assigning the query variable to CommandText must be the *first* thing you do.